# Error install IO::Pty perl

Tags: perl, cpan, net-sftp

install IO::Pty cpan

```
Tty.xs:54:23: sys/ioctl.h: No such file or directory
Tty.xs: In function `make_safe_fd':
Tty.xs:225: error: `F_DUPFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
Tty.xs:225: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Tty.xs:225: error: for each function it appears in.)
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Tty.o'
TODDR/IO-Tty-1.10.tar.gz
C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
```

no SFTP module is getting install.

Answer (score 0):

First, that distribution is called `IO::Tty` (which contains an `IO::Pty` module).

You seem to be missing some header files for a C library your module is linking to. You would have to install the headers beforehand. However… [`ioctl` is Unix-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) and a part of the operating system. It is also notoriously unportable.

I could not find any [reports of a IO::Tty install working on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=IO-Tty), so it seems you can't use that module on Windows (without a Cygwin environment). As it happens this is also what the [`IO::Tty` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aTty#DESCRIPTION) says:

> Windows is now supported, but ONLY under the Cygwin environment, see http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/.